# Is there a keyboard shortcut to obtain a non-breaking hyphen?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, gedit

I am writing [Pandoc Markdown](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html) in the `gedit` text editor. From time to time, I need a [non‑breaking hyphen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_hyphen#Nonbreaking_hyphens). (By the way, the hyphen in the previous sentence is one!) So far, I have been copying non-breaking hyphens from the character map which is quite cumbersome. This made me look for a quicker alternative...

Hence, my question: **Is there any keyboard shortcut to obtain a non‑breaking hyphen?**

Alas, modifier keys do not seem to offer any help here...

[image: Belgian linux keyboard layout]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and then type `2011` followed by <kbd>Space</kbd> which will turn into <kbd>‑</kbd> (non‑breaking hyphen).

Comment: Thanks. Finishing off with `Enter ⏎` instead of `Space` also works.